# MySQL join 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've problems join 4 mysql tables for my callmanagement.

My tables are :

```
calls:
callId | contactId | companyId | numberId | timestamp | callNote | duration | state

contacts:
contactId | firstName | lastName | companyId | email | contactNote

numbers:
numberId | contactId | number

companies:
companyId | companyName
```

I need a query which gives me:

```
callId | timestamp | duration | number | callNote | state | contactId | firstName | lastName | company | email | contactNote
```

I think it's possible,but I don't know how.

Comment: OK. What stops you? Have you already studied `INNER JOIN`s? Have you identified your Primary and Foreign keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
select o.callId , o.timestamp , o.duration ,o.callNote ,
o.state,o.contactId,
  j.firstName , j.lastName ,j.company Id as company,
  j.email, j.contactNote,

r.number

from calls o 
left outer join contacts j 
  on o.contactId =j.contactId  
left outer join numbers r 
  on j.contactId=r.contactId;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `INNER JOIN` to join up the tables. For example:

```
SELECT 
    c.callId, 
    c.timestamp, 
    c.duration, 
    n.number, 
    c.callNote, 
    c.state, 
    c.contactId, 
    c1.firstName,
    c1.lastName, 
    c2.CompanyName as company, 
    c1.email, 
    c1.contactNote
FROM calls c 
INNER JOIN contacts c1 ON c1.contacId = c.contactId
INNER JOIN numbers n ON n.contactId = c1.contactid
INNER JOIN companies c2 ON c2.companyid = c.companyid
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
SELECT
     calls.CallId
    ,calls.[Timestamp]
    ,calls.[duration]
    ,numbers.number
    ,calls.callNote
    ,calls.[state]
    ,calls.contactId
    ,contacts.firstName
    ,contacts.lastName
    ,companies.companyName AS company
    ,contacts.email
    ,contacts.contactNote
FROM
           calls
INNER JOIN contacts     ON calls.contactId = contacts.Id
INNER JOIN numbers      ON calls.contactId = numbers.contactId
                            AND calls.numberId = numbers.numberId                   
INNER JOIN companies    ON contacts.companyId = companies.companyId
```

Presumably it is possible for one contact to have more than one number, so unless you join to numbers on contactId AND numberId, you may find that you get duplication in your results, as the query will not know how to join to the numbers table.

Comment: for my own understanding, please could you explain the down vote on the solution - I'm not sure what my error is.